# Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

Tags: java, javafx, mouseevent

Here is the error

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = Group@5ea0c6fc
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$3.onProposedChange(Unknown Source)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.add(Unknown Source)
at project1.Crab.setCrab(Crab.java:45)
at project1.SeaAnimals.addCrab(SeaAnimals.java:65)
at project1.ProjectOne.mouseClick(ProjectOne.java:133)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8300(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1300(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is the lines of code that have the problem

```
public class Crab {

    private final Image c = new Image("File:crab.gif");
    private ArrayList<ImageView> crabList = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
    private int _counter;
    private Group _crab = new Group();
    /** Constructor <br>
     * Initializes counter to -1
     */
    public Crab() {
        _counter = -1;
    }
    /** Setter <br>
     * Adds a crab to the array list
     */
    public void addCrab() {
        if(_counter < 5) {
            crabList.add(new ImageView(c));
            _counter++;
        }
    }
    /** Setter <br> 
     * Deletes a crab from the array list
     */
    public void deleteCrab() {
        if(_counter > 0) {
            crabList.remove(_counter);
            _counter--;
        }
    }
    /** Getter <br>
     * 
     * @return returns crab group
     */
    public Group setCrab() {
        if(_counter >= 0) { //adds the first crab
            crabList.get(0).setTranslateX(80);
            crabList.get(0).setTranslateY(500);
            crabList.get(0).setFitHeight(100);
            crabList.get(0).setFitWidth(100);
            _crab.getChildren().add(crabList.get(0));
            if(_counter >= 1) { //adds the second crab
                crabList.get(1).setTranslateX(230);
                crabList.get(1).setTranslateY(500);
                crabList.get(1).setFitHeight(100);
                crabList.get(1).setFitWidth(100);
                _crab.getChildren().add(crabList.get(1));       
                if (_counter >= 2) { // adds the third crab
                    crabList.get(2).setTranslateX(380);
                    crabList.get(2).setTranslateY(500);
                    crabList.get(2).setFitHeight(100);
                    crabList.get(2).setFitWidth(100);
                    _crab.getChildren().add(crabList.get(2));
                    if (_counter >= 3) { //adds the fourth crab
                        crabList.get(3).setTranslateX(530);
                        crabList.get(3).setTranslateY(500);
                        crabList.get(3).setFitHeight(100);
                        crabList.get(3).setFitWidth(100);
                        _crab.getChildren().add(crabList.get(3));   
                        if (_counter >= 4) { //adds the fifth crab
                            crabList.get(4).setTranslateX(680);
                            crabList.get(4).setTranslateY(500);
                            crabList.get(4).setFitHeight(100);
                            crabList.get(4).setFitWidth(100);
                            _crab.getChildren().add(crabList.get(4));           
                            if (_counter == 5) { //adds the sixth crab
                                crabList.get(5).setTranslateX(830);
                                crabList.get(5).setTranslateY(500);
                                crabList.get(5).setFitHeight(100);
                                crabList.get(5).setFitWidth(100);
                                _crab.getChildren().add(crabList.get(5));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return _crab;
    }
}
```

```
    public Group addCrab() {
        _crab.addCrab();
        _gCrab = _crab.setCrab();
        return _gCrab;
    }
    public Group deleteCrab() {
        _crab.deleteCrab();
        _gCrab = _crab.setCrab();
        return _gCrab;
    }
}
```

```
public void mouseClick(MouseEvent mouse) {
    if(mouse.getClickCount() == 1) {
        root.getChildren().remove(gCrab);
        gCrab.getChildren().clear();
        gCrab.getChildren().add(animals.addCrab());
        root.getChildren().add(gCrab);
    }
    else if(mouse.getClickCount() == 2) {
        root.getChildren().remove(gCrab);
        gCrab.getChildren().clear();
        gCrab.getChildren().add(animals.deleteCrab());
        root.getChildren().add(gCrab);
    }
}
```

I do not know how to fix the problem, nor do I know what the problem is. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this happen the first or second time you click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `setCrab` method attempts to add all the crab images to the `Group` without removing any of the children. This way if there were crabs in the `Group` before you're trying to add them again which results in the exception since JavaFX does not allow this.

You also need to make sure never to add the same node twice to the same parent.

Furthermore hiding the `setCrab` from the user of the `Crab` class would reduce the complexity of using the class. Why make the user call 2 methods when 1 call would do the same job. You could even write a `CrabGroup` class that is a node itself and aviod the removing and readding of the `Group` to it's parent.

E.g.

```
public class CrabGroup extends HBox {

    private static final Image c = new Image("File:crab.gif");

    public CrabGroup() {
        setSpacing(50);
    }

    /**
     * Adds a crab
     */
    public void addCrab() {
        if(getChildren().size() < 6) {
            ImageView image = new ImageView(c);
            image.setFitWidth(100);
            image.setFitHeight(100);
            crabList.add(image);
        }
    }

    /** 
     * Deletes a crab
     */
    public void deleteCrab() {
        if(!getChildren().isEmpty()) {
            getChildren().remove(getChildren().size() - 1);
        }
    }

}
```

```
CrabGroup crabGroup = new CrabGroup();
crabGroup.setTranslateX(80);
crabGroup.setTranslateY(500);
```

```
crabGroup.addCrab();
...
crabGroup.deleteCrab();
```